# Extending dynamic dispatch to call functions in the view model?

Tags: c#, oop, dynamic-dispatch

I'm using MVVM in a Xamarin application, I have an interface to navigate between pages:

```
public interface INavigate
    {
        INavigate Next();
        INavigate Previous();
        string ViewTitle { get; }
    }
```

In the implementing views:

```
public partial class V2Upload : ContentView, INavigate
    {
        public string ViewTitle => "Upload photos";

        public INavigate Next()
            => new V3AdDetail();

        public INavigate Previous()
            => new V1Agreement();
    }
```

and in the view model
I have a property of type `INavigate`:

```
    public INavigate CurrentAddItemStep
    {
        get { return _currentAddItemStep; }
        set { Set(ref _currentAddItemStep, value); }
    }
```

and the Content property of the parent view is bound to this property:

when next button is clicked I execute this code:

```
CurrentAddItemStep = CurrentAddItemStep.Next();
ViewTitle = CurrentAddItemStep.ViewTitle;
```

now a validation method is required before navigating to the next page for all the Content views..
I  want to keep the MVVM pattern as clean as possible by not writing business code in the view, for example in the `V2Upload` view the `File1` and `File2` properties of the view model shouldn't be `null`:

```
private bool ValidateFiles(){

     return (File1 ?? File2) != null;
}
```

but since the navigating is done dynamically in run-time, I can't know which view is the current view.
I'm thinking to use reflection , to know what is the name of the view (but this will break the whole design)

Another option is to provide a function parameter to the `Next`  method, but also how to provide it in the design time from the view model?

This is what I'm doing now:

```
  public INavigate Next()
        {
            if (((ViewModel.AddItemViewModel)BindingContext).ValidateFiles())
                return new V3AdDetail();
            else
                return this;
        }
```

but again, I'm accessing the view model from the view (and had to change the `ValidateFiles` method from `private` to `public`), which I want to avoid

Comment: You've got a good pattern going...why not extend your interface to include, say `bool CanGoBack()` and `bool CanGoForward()` ... and let them call validation as necessary? Your base view model class could provide default implementations returning `true` if you don't want to muddy up all your view models. You'd have to make your next button code a little more stateful, but your MVVM would be clean.

Comment: @Clay but the view model doesn't know what view is being set so it can't decide which validation to run!
do you mean to implement validation in the INavigate implementation (the view)?

Comment: Sorry - read it backwards. What I was trying to get to...is that I'd expect all my view models to derive from a useful base class (or implement an interface) that I could call `CanGoBack()` or `CanGoForward()` without having to know the current view model. Basically, it's adding methods to your MVVM infrastructure.

Comment: I guess the observation that led me to the first comment was that I'd think the ViewModel might want to be the responsible party to dictate where we're going next...and I was lazy in reading that the the View is presently making those decisions.

Comment: Yes, what I need is to find a way so that the vm decide which validation to run, and I think the only way for this is to let it know which view is being rendered, which will break the design and I'll set view manually, which I hope I don't have to

Comment: Do you not have a separate VM for each view?

Comment: @Clay , the parent view is of type `ContentPage` and the four views are of type `Content View : INavigate` then I set the Content property of the Content Page to one of them on each next/previous, thus I have only one view model that all views share. Hope this make sense to you, as it makes sense rather than if the four children have a separate view model, all the views just represent a single process of adding an item. But due to the limitation of mobile screens I devided the process into four views